# How to set a promotional image in the Chrome Extensions list?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I can see that a lot of Chrome Extensions have a promotional image in the list. For example with gmail :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/gmail?hl=fr&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

I don't find where to set this image in the Developer Dashboard. How to ?

Comment: Did you try the promotional image section right below screenshots?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Visit the [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and click on the Edit link.
Scroll down (below the screenshots section), and upload the images for your extension:

[image]

The images will be put in the review queue after uploading it. If the images meet the [criteria for promotional images](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images?hl=en#promo), it will show up in the Web store within a few days.

You won't get *any* notifications when the images get (dis)approved. Send a message to cws-assets@google.com to query the status of your images. And no, you can't see the status at the dashboard, contrary to what the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images#promo) states.

Comment: Ok. I already did it but I didn't know that they were been waiting for validation.