# Several problems with icons during Chrome Extension development

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, chrome-web-store

It's very strange.

### 1 problem

If I add this icon declaration to my manifest:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
```

Then, when I add Extension through "Load unpacked extensions ... " it doesn't show logo
[image]

But if you try to delete it, it does show
[image]

AND! If I delete "48" line from manifect, it starts showing it right away. Maybe it's because I use Chrome Beta (Version 28.0.1500.20 beta) or maybe because I do something wrong.

### Seconds problem

Is about icon on Web Store.
I have good 128x128 icon but for some reason in several places it doesn't used in HI-res.
Icon is the following: [image]

But those looks very bad
[image]
[image]

Also on the last screenshot it puts my logo inside Puzzle icon. I saw many other plugins where it doesn't put it like this.

**So I guess my question is following: What icon sized should I provide to have it looks nice in all places?**

Answer (score 6):

1. *Close* the `chrome://extensions/` tab, and re-open it. This may fix the issue (I've experienced this bug a couple of times)
2. On the details page, only icons of [apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html) are fully shown. **All [extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)** are displayed within a puzzle in the Chrome Web Store.

   If you want to get a different picture at the search results, upload a promotional image at the dashboard. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856099/938089) for details.

Comment: I've added 440x280 one, but it still the same in Search result. I guess it takes time. When it become new, I'll mark this question as right =)

Comment: Important note (though it's spelled out in the linked answer): adding a promo image to the listing triggers a manual review and is not immediately applied.