# Chrome Web Store Search Icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've just published a Chrome extension, but am having difficulties displaying the right icon for my extension in the Web Store.

Here is what is currently being displayed:

[image]

Here is the icon context in my manifest:

```
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon02.png",
    "48": "icon02.png",
    "128": "promoSmall.png"
  },
```

The image being displayed it icon02.png, I'm trying to display promoSmall.png.

Where is the image from the store page looking at?

Note: I understand that this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854005/several-problems-with-icons-during-chrome-extension-development). I believe this question is more specific, and may serve more useful to others with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the linked answer does answer your question. As such, voting to close as duplicate. In the search result, a scaled-down _small promotional tile_ image is displayed if available. If you added one to the listing, **make sure it actually passed review**, they are not applied immediately.

Comment: @Xan Once again, thank you for your help. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: I think your question is well-worded, and as such useful. I even upvoted it. Let it stay even if it will be closed as a duplicate.