# Chrome extension is displayed in searches using the wrong image

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have published a Chrome extension, uploaded all the required images, including icon and promotional images (which were approved).

The resulted icon appears of much lower resolution (blurred) than the uploaded one. In the search list, the extension image appears as the low resolution icon, instead of either the promotional image or the updated icon.

I can see the majority of the other extension search images displayed correctly (very few are similar to mine), so I understand that this issue is common to a few developers only.

You can see below a comparison between mine and a correct one.

Would you please help me fix these issues?

[image: Comparison between displayed images for 2 extensions]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854005/several-problems-with-icons-during-chrome-extension-development

Comment: I want to thank the person who solved the issue of using the wrong image in the search list.  Now the search list shows the correct promotional image.  However the icon showed on the Extension page is still of very low resolution.

Comment: I have figured it out: The icon displayed there is a scaled down version of the stored icon with a resolution of 24x24 px. The same stays true for all extensions. Only apps have a better displayed icon. Why would it be so small, I don't understand.