# Having trouble setting my listing icon in the chrome web store

Tags: chrome-web-store

I'm having trouble setting my icon for the Chrome Web Store.

For example:

[image]

Is the monkey in the first row the promotional image, or is it being set as an icon?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm curious where the option in the Chrome Web Store is? If I'm missing something.

Comment: I think I'm doing a poor job of clarifying what I'm trying to find a solution to. I would like to know which setting in the Chrome Web Store controls the monkey image that you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0upv12uiccysgsx/Screenshot%202014-01-02%2009.56.53.png

Comment: See edit to question.

Comment: Great thanks for your help. Do you have any ideas on what the solution might be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a promotional image in the Chrome Extensions list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855373/how-to-set-a-promotional-image-in-the-chrome-extensions-list)

Comment: It's the 440x280 picture. See [How to set a promotional image in the Chrome Extensions list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855373/how-to-set-a-promotional-image-in-the-chrome-extensions-list) for more information. The most relevant part to your specific question is "The images will be put in the review queue after uploading it. If the images meet the [criteria for promotional images](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images?hl=en#promo), they will show up in the Web store within a few days.".